# Contact Person details in shopify

Tags: shopify

How to show the list of user who fill the contact form in shopify?
Can someone tell me what fields and in which table store this info?
how to get it and show in the shopify admin dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

There is no way to show the users who submitted the contact form in Shopify. This information is not stored in the back end so you don't have access to it.

The only way to get this information is to review all of the emails that were send to the designated email address in the store.